# How can I check if authorization is successful using java Authenticator?

Tags: java, authorization

I use Authenticator to login to the server like that:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication ("admin", "*****".toCharArray());
   }
});
```

It works fine.
But how can I ensure that authorization is actually successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The class Authenticator represents an object that knows how to obtain authentication for a network connection. Usually, it will do this by prompting the user for information.

what you have done so far is registering an instance of the anonymous class with the system, now all you have to do is to define a URL and connect to it.

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.1/");// Connecting to this URL requires username and password to be entered.
```

However I don't think there is a common way to check if login was successful or not, i think that your gonna have to read the parse the http response and try to extract useful information from it, for example.

```
if (response.contains("HREF=css/login.css"))
//login failed
```

Comment: It looks like workaround. This is a kind of common scenario. Didn't they indeed expect unsuccessful authorization case?

Comment: unfortunately not, there is no such thing as `getLoginStatus();`, I think that you will have to improvise :(